# SQL Server ignores gel symbol

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why does Server ignore the ₾ symbol ?

Why this:

```
print iif(N'₾' = N'', 'true', 'false')
```

is the same as:

```
print iif(N'₾2' = N'2', 'true', 'false')
```

What role does collation play in this situation and what is happening under the hood?

Comment: Interesting. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=036e15696890713fcd197db05e0757d9) - BIN/BIN2 collations work

Comment: probably the same issue with non weighted characters as https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/171331/3690

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that this is an issue related to the Unicode version when the character was introduced and the type of SQL Server collation that is used:

- The € character was introduced in Unicode 2.1 and it returns `false` in all collations
- The ₭ character was introduced in Unicode 3.0 and it returns `false` in the old collations (for example Latin1_General_CI_AS), but it returns `true` in the collations introduced in SQL Server 2008 (for example Latin1_General_100_CI_AS)
- The ẞ character was introduced in Unicode 5.1 and it returns `true` in most collations, but it returns `false` in the collations introduced in SQL Server 2017 (for example Japanese_Bushu_Kakusu_140_CI_AS_VSS)
- The ₸ character was introduced in Unicode 5.2 and it returns `true` in all collations (except BIN collations)
- The ₾ character was introduced in Unicode 8.0 and it returns `true` in all collations (except BIN collations)